# Why function can't accept array alias

Tags: arrays, go

Why function can't accept pointer of alias type of array

```golang
type numbers [10]int

func lol(nums *numbers) {
    fmt.Println(nums)
}

func main() {
    a := [10]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    lol(&a)
}

// error: cannot use &a (type *[10]int) as type *numbers in argument to lol
```

if it doesn't accept pointer then it's work

Comment: `numbers` is **not** an "alias". There are  aliases in Go but numbers isn't. See. "Alias decleration" in https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations. Note that all these language fundamentals about types are covered in the Tour of Go and can be looked up easily in the language spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
type numbers [10]int
```

is a [type definition](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions).  The statement defines a new and distinct type. The statement does not declare an [alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Alias_declarations).

A `*[10]int` is not [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to a `*number`. Use a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to pass the address of `a` to `lol`:

```
lol((*numbers)(&a))
```

A different fix is to declare `a` as type `numbers`:

```
a := numbers{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
lol(&a)
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought it's the same since its definition same.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
type numbers [10]int
```

Is a "type definition", as opposed to a "type alias":

```golang
type numbers = [10]int
```

[A type definition creates a new type, as opposed to an alias, which binds an identifier to the given type.](https://alehatsman.com/posts/golang_type_declaration_abuse.html)

Type aliases are not recommended for casual use, and as mentioned in [Muffin Top's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64530939/1486968), you would be better off declaring `a` as type `numbers`.